# Поиск строк по регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо найти такие строки:

```
/group-avvsgng.php
/group-vvzb_hl.php
```

Но исключить такие:

```
/kabel-1-kv_v_group-vvgng_t.php
/kabel-10-kv_v_group-apvbbshv.php
```

Пробовал так, но исключения тоже находит:

```
/[^\s].*(?!_)group-[^>]+.php/ig
```

Answer (score 0):

Организовать поиск символа `/`, за которым следует одна и более букв `group`, за которыми следует обязательная группа символов, состоящих из тире и одной и более букв `-vvzb`, за которыми следует не обязательная группа символов, состоящих из символа подчёркивания и одной и более букв `_hl`, за которыми следует точка `.`, после которой следуют три буквы `php`:

```
$str = '/group-avvsgng.php и /group-vvzb_hl.php и /position/kabel-1-kv_v_group-vvgng_t.php и /position/kabel-10-kv_v_group-apvbbshv.php';

$patt = '~/\pL+(?:-\pL+(?:_\pL+)?)+\.\pL{3}~';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "/group-avvsgng.php"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "/group-vvzb_hl.php"
  }
}
```

---

**UPD**: Если требуется найти соответствия, начинающиеся со слова `/group`, тогда можно сократить шаблон:

```
$str = '/group-avvsgng.php и /group-vvzb_hl.php и /position/kabel-1-kv_v_group-vvgng_t.php и /position/kabel-10-kv_v_group-apvbbshv.php';

$patt = '~/group\S+~';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: спасибо. но не работает корректно у меня

Comment: @md5hash а как вы используете этот код - какие строки передаёте, и что получаете на выходе?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = `
/group-avvsgng.php
/group-vvzb_hl.php
/kabel-1-kv_v_group-vvgng_t.php
/kabel-10-kv_v_group-apvbbshv.php
`

const matchResult = str.match(/\/group-.+\.php/g);
console.log(matchResult);
```

Comment: а если например такие ссылки: /position/kabel-1-kv_v_group-vvgng_t.php  и /position/kabel-10-kv_v_group-apvbbshv.php ?

Comment: Через 30 минут изменю, ну или попробуйте заменить `\/group` на `.+\/group`

Comment: а в чем проблема? работает и с этими строками без изменений

Comment: странно у меня почему то нет

Comment: я правильно понимаю что `/position/kabel-1-kv_v_group-vvgng_t.php` должна игнорироваться?

Comment: да       /position/kabel-1-kv_v_group-vvgng_t.php должна игнорироваться

Comment: Можно пример кода где эта строка не игнорируется?